# Mosquitto access control - Pattern and user restriction

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to create a pattern for regular users access control, as well as an "admin" user which has different permissions.

Before the pattern, I've had:

```
user admin
topic write +/in/#
topic read +/out/#

user john
topic read john/in/#
topic write john/out/#
```

And that works fine. However, when introducing more users, a pattern is needed. What I've concluded from Mosquitto's datasheet, translates to:

```
user admin
topic write +/in/#
topic read +/out/#

pattern read %u/in/#
pattern write %u/out/#
```

However, with the above configuration, connection is denied. What did I do wrong with the above configuration?

I will also add that the patterns alone (without "admin" user configuration), it works fine. The problem that I'm facing is when I have both a pattern and specific user access control.

Edit: might be good to add mosquitto(v1.4.15)'s configuration:

```
allow_anonymous false
password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwd
acl_file /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/access_control

message_size_limit 1000
use_username_as_clientid true

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_dest topic
connection_messages true
log_type all
```

Comment: Please also add what version of mosquitto you are using

Comment: Also since you are using username as client id what happens if you swap `%u` for `%c`?

Comment: Added. Also tried swapping with %c but the result is the same. It was a good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the user specific patterns after the general patterns.

e.g.

```
pattern read %u/in/#
pattern write %u/out/#

user admin
topic write +/in/#
topic read +/out/#
```

This is because all patterns following a `user` entry are assumed to belong to that user.

EDIT:

Actually the [doc](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) implies otherwise, but I'd still give this a try.

> The substitution pattern must be the only text for that level of
>   hierarchy. Pattern ACLs apply to all users even if the "user" keyword
>   has previously been given.

Comment: Hi, I tried what you suggested. Connection is still denied.